# Cannot resolve snapshot from Artifactory due to snapshot / release handling policy

Tags: gradle, artifactory

So I've searched around for an answer for this but had no luck.

Basically we are deploying SNAPSHOT versions of a JAR using a Jenkins task and we end up with a structure in Artifactory something like this

`| - dep-jar
        |- 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
            |- dep-jar-0.0.1-20141014.145441-1.jar`

This all seems fine and Artifactory lists the dependency dec for gradle as:

```
compile(group: 'blah', name: 'dep-jar', version: '0.0.37-20141015.142042-1')
```

Trouble is, when you try and resolve this using Gradle you get a 409 conflict, i.e. rejected due to snapshot/release handling policy.

If I try

```
compile(group: 'blah', name: 'dep-jar', version: '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT')
```

It just completely fails to find anything.

Any ideas what i'm doing wrong here?

Thanks

Comment: What's your 'repositories' declaration look like?

Answer (score 4):

As of Gradle 2.1, Gradle doesn't support resolving a snapshot dependency using its unique version number (it's a known limitation). `0.0.1-SNAPSHOT` should work, provided that Maven coordinates and repo declarations are correct. Your dependency declarations aren't consistent with respect to version number (0.0.1 vs. 0.0.37), so maybe the coordinates aren't correct.

Answer (score 0):

I got the issue, because i put below code in gradle.properities

```
systemProp.http.proxyHost=127.0.0.1
systemProp.http.proxyPort=1080
```

**My solution**

remove the proxy from the gradle.properities.